# Installation of GitLab ignores ./config/gitlab.yml

Tags: centos, centos5, git, gitolite, gitlab

I have been trying to install GitLab on CentOS 5.x, but I am stuck now and google's are confusing.

I have been following [this install guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/stable/doc/installation.md) (currently stuck [**here**](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/stable/doc/installation.md#setup-db))

After running `bundle exec rake gitlab:app:status RAILS_ENV=production` for the secund time I get this output:

```
Starting diagnostic
config/database.yml............exists
config/gitlab.yml............exists
/home/git/repositories/............missing
rake aborted!
unexpected return
```

The relevant part from `/home/gitlab/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml` is this (server has custom shh port):

```
git_host:
  system: gitolite___
  admin_uri: git@localhost:gitolite-admin
  base_path: /home/git/repositories/
  host: localhost
  git_user: git
  port: 2134
```

Folder permissions are `drwxrwx--- 4 git  git  4096 Jul 20 07:12 repositories` and the files inside are (`gitlab` user is in `git` group):

```
drwxrwx--- 8 git git 4096 Jul 20 04:22 gitolite-admin.git
drwxrwx--- 7 git git 4096 Jul 20 04:22 testing.git
```

Thing, even if I change the `base_path` value in  `config/gitlab.yml`, it keeps trying to look up the same folder.

Only possible directions for the solution, that I found on google, indicated, that it is somehow related to SElinux. The suggested command was: `find . -print0 |xargs -0 -n 1 sudo setfattr -h -x security.selinux`. But i have no clue where to execute it and it tells me that `command setfattr not found` .. or something. Also, I kinda doubt, that unchanging configuration might too be affected by SElinux.

What to do ?

Comment: In your case, the repos are in `/home/git/repositories/`? Or are they in `/home/gitlab/repositories/`

Comment: they are in `/home/git/repositories/`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you did not run the `rake` command as your gitlab user? As in:

```
sudo -u gitlab bundle exec rake gitlab:app:status RAILS_ENV=production
```

Had a similar problem, seeing other settings from `gitlab.yml` just not being applied...

Answer (score 0):

You mention:

> Thing, even if I change the base_path value in `config/gitlab.yml`, it keeps trying to look up the same folder.

If you look at the [`config/initializers/1_settings.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/initializers/1_settings.rb#L65-L67) program:

```
def git_base_path
      git_host['base_path'] || '/home/git/repositories/'
end
```

So this is your real issue here (before starting tweaking the folder permissions): gitlab somehow ignores your `config/gitlab.yml` setting.
Double-check for any typo in it, and make sure it is taken into account at all (by removing it for instance, to see if gitlab complains about that file missing).

Comment: I have v2.6.3 but there is no such file

Comment: @teresko try installing from `master`, following https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/installation.md, and see if the issue persists.